# Can dataframe processed with StandartScaler contain values >1 or <-1?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, standard-deviation

i scale my feature dataframe as follows:

```py
flattened_num_f.head()
num_features_test  = flattened_num_f.fillna(flattened_num_f.mean())

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
std_scaler = StandardScaler()

num_train_std = pd.DataFrame(std_scaler.fit_transform(num_features_test.loc[y_train_IDs]), \
                         columns=num_features_test.loc[y_train_IDs].columns, \
                        index=num_features_test.loc[y_train_IDs].index)
test_for_stdness(num_train_std)
```

the last function adds values that fall beyond [-1, 1] constraints to list,
It finds ~100 elements , max : 78.86000099160675, min :-2.785050711746339

Is it normal, or have i made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StandardScaler does the conversion based on standard normal distribution (whose mean is zero and standard deviation is 1). In this distribution, the random variable can take any value between -infinity and infinity. Larger values will be more unlikely but they can appear. In fact, the probability that you can see a value smaller than -1 or larger than 1 is around 32%. [image].

See [this Khan Academy page](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/normal-distributions-a2/normal-distributions-a2ii/a/basic-normal-calculations) for the source of the image and some example calculations.

In a standard min-max normalization where you subtract the minimum value and divide by the range, you get values between 0 and 1 but this can be modified with a linear function so you can get values between -1 and 1.